# How can I exclude a java file conditionally with the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin and bootJar task?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have some code that I do not want included in the jar file based on a condition.

My build script looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            if (project.environment == 'prod') {
                exclude '**/dangerous/**'
            }
            forEach {
                println it.absolutePath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the script with `gradlew clean build bootJar -Penvironment=prod` the absolute paths of everything but the dangerous java files is printed, but they are *still* included in the jar.

If I remove the boot plugin and run the `jar` task, the dangerous class files are *still* included in the jar.

`gradlew clean build jar -Penvironment=prod`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            if (project.environment == 'prod') {
                exclude '**/dangerous/**'
            }
            forEach {
                println it.absolutePath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I add an `exclude` clause to the jar task, the dangerous files are not printed, *and* they are not included in the jar.

`gradlew clean build jar -Penvironment=prod`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            if (project.environment == 'prod') {
                exclude '**/dangerous/**'
            }
            forEach {
                println it.absolutePath
            }
        }
    }
}

jar {
    exclude '**/dangerous/**'
}
```

If I enable the boot plugin, and use the bootJar task (which inherits from the Jar task) (`gradlew clean build bootJar -Penvironment=prod`), I do not see the dangerous files printed, **but the files are still included in the jar**.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            if (project.environment == 'prod') {
                exclude '**/dangerous/**'
            }
            forEach {
                println it.absolutePath
            }
        }
    }
}

bootJar {
    exclude '**/dangerous/**'
}
```

How can I exclude a java file conditionally with the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin and bootJar task?

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue when i was using 2.0.1.RELEASE. I created jar using bootJar option. Add exclude inside it with file patterns which you want to exclude from executable jar.
This worked fine with spring 2.0.4.RELEASE version.

```
bootJar {
    exclude("**/dangerous/*")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed down the problem. I didn't put in all of the plugins up above, because I thought the only important ones were java and spring boot. However, my actual code also uses the `protobuf` plugin. If I remove the configuration property `generatedFilesBaseDir`, then it successfully excludes the `dangerous` directory.

However, this opens up a new question of, *what the hell is happening?*

I was specifying the generated files base dir property so I could reference the generated classes in my source code, but I think I may need to create a different project just for the proto, and add that project as a reference to my main module.

## Edit

Making a separate project for the protobuf files and referencing it as a project seems to be a viable workaround for this issue.